# Redshift create list and search different table with it

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I think there a few ways to tackle this, but I'm not sure how to do any of them.
I have two tables, the first has ID's and Numbers. The ID's and numbers can potentially be listed more than once, so I create a result table that lists the unique numbers grouped by ID.

My second table has rows (100 million) with the ID and Numbers again. I need to search that table for any ID that has a Number not in the list of Numbers from the result table.

Can redshift do a query based on if the ID matches and the Number exists in the list from the table?  Can this all be done in memory/one statement?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `myTable`;

CREATE TABLE `myTable` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ID` varchar(255),
  `Numbers` mediumint default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `myTable` (`ID`,`Numbers`)
VALUES
  ("CRQ44MPX1SZ",1890),
  ("UHO21QQY3TW",4370),
  ("JTQ62CBP6ER",1825),
  ("RFD95MLC2MI",5014),
  ("URZ04HGG2YQ",2859),
 ("CRQ44MPX1SZ",1891),
  ("UHO21QQY3TW",4371),
  ("JTQ62CBP6ER",1826),
  ("RFD95MLC2MI",5015),
  ("URZ04HGG2YQ",2860),
 ("CRQ44MPX1SZ",1892),
  ("UHO21QQY3TW",4372),
  ("JTQ62CBP6ER",1827),
  ("RFD95MLC2MI",5016),
  ("URZ04HGG2YQ",2861);


SELECT ID, listagg(distinct Numbers,',') as Number_List, count(Numbers) as Numbers_Count
FROM myTable
GROUP BY ID
AS result


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `myTable2`;

CREATE TABLE `myTable2` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `ID` varchar(255),
  `Numbers` mediumint default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

INSERT INTO `myTable2` (`ID`,`Numbers`)
VALUES
  ("CRQ44MPX1SZ",1870),
  ("UHO21QQY3TW",4350),
  ("JTQ62CBP6ER",1825),
  ("RFD95MLC2MI",5014),
  ("URZ04HGG2YQ",2859),
 ("CRQ44MPX1SZ",1891),
  ("UHO21QQY3TW",4371),
  ("JTQ62CBP6ER",1826),
  ("RFD95MLC2MI",5015),
  ("URZ04HGG2YQ",2860),
 ("CRQ44MPX1SZ",1882),
  ("UHO21QQY3TW",4372),
  ("JTQ62CBP6ER",1827),
  ("RFD95MLC2MI",5016),
  ("URZ04HGG2YQ",2861);
```

Pseudo Code

```
Select ID, listagg(distinct Numbers) as Violation
Where Numbers IN NOT IN result.Numbers_List


or possibly: WHERE Numbers NOT LIKE '%' || result.Numbers_List|| '%'
```

Desired Output

```
(“CRQ44MPX1SZ”, ”1870,1882”)
(“UHO21QQY3TW”, ”4350”)
```

**EDIT**
Going the JOIN route, I am not getting the right results...but I'm pretty sure my WHERE implementation is wrong.

```
SELECT mytable1.ID, listagg(distinct mytable2.Numbers, ',') as unauth_list, count(mytable2.Numbers) as unauth_count
FROM mytable1
LEFT JOIN mytable2 on mytable1.id = mytable2.id
WHERE (mytable1.id = mytable2.id)
AND (mytable1.Numbers <> mytable2.Numbers)
GROUP BY mytable1.id
```

Expected output:

```
(“CRQ44MPX1SZ”, ”1870,1882”, 2)
(“UHO21QQY3TW”, ”4350”, 1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just left join the two tables on ID and numbers and check for (where clause) to see if the match wasn't found.  Shouldn't be a need for listagg() and complex comparing. Or did I miss part of the question?

Comment: Yes, I think that would work too. I was just stuck thinking about how I would do it in Python I guess.   The problem I am having with the JOIN is that it's not returning the expected result. So I know I'm implementing it wrong.  I'll update my question.

Comment: I made a quick sqlfiddle with a join.  Does this help? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f1442/7